# osgi multiple versions of service

Tags: jboss, osgi, osgi-bundle

i have osgi services service-1.0.0.jar and service-1.1.0.jar they are implementation of service-api-1.0.0.jar

both these service-1.0.0.jar and service-1.1.0.jar have same service name and packages.

service are registered by bundle-activator

lets assume bundle activator is com.abc.xyz.MyActivator - 1.0.0 and 1.1.0

issue I am facing is when I deploy these services and lookup using service tracker and filter on version I want, I always get same implementation regardless of what version chosen.

this makes me believe that what i am trying to achieve is not doable. 
I need multiple implementation of service packaged in separate bundles with difference of version and be able to choose dynamically at runtime.

I am trying this in jboss-6.1.1 eap

if i keep different package name in versions looks like it is able to understand that these are 2 different services but when package names are same i get same service implementation.

am i doing something wrong? has anybody tried this?

is it correct that OSGI allow you to deploy multiple versions of service?

*UPDATE* **After using unique package names for MyActivator in 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 looks like the services are able to maintain the uniqueness.**

Does that mean Activators has to unique across bundles?

Comment: How do you filter for the version?

Comment: you can filter using OBJECTCLASS and get all serviceReferences and iterate over and do the bundle.getVersion something like that

Comment: The Activator names do not have to be unique between bundles as long as their package is private. In general you should try to hide the implementation of the service by not exporting the package.

Comment: That makes sense. My activator package by default was exported. I have strong feeling

Comment: Christian Thanks for the right answer. 
I was missing Private-Package: com.app.service.impl
I wish I could vote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `service-api-1.0.0.jar` exports the package which defines the service interface. In that case, it sounds like you have two implementations of the same version of the service. Not different implementations of different versions of the service. So from a service user point of view, the services are that same: they are from the same service api package version.

Comment: This is not so straight forward. In this case Client does not export anything. There is loose coupling between the client and services. Client only knows about the service name and version.

Comment: So the client does not know the Java type of the service? And this type is not exported by service-api and imported by clients?

Comment: Right! client is using reflection. Looks like what I am trying to do should work?

Comment: please check my update after using unique package names for Activators only everything seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the OSGi services in a strange way. As a client you should not look into the implemention bundles to determine versions or other informations.

Instead you should use the service interface and service properties to distinguish between services.

So for example you can have a property version and publish the first service with version=1 and the second with version=2. Then you can filter for this property to get a specific service.

Using reflection is also a rather unusual thing. Better try to provide classes in the interface package that you use to exchange data between client and service. This will make the client less dependent on the service impl.

Comment: Are you saying that one can have one implementation to one service api?
I am trying to test exactly opposite, I need multiple implementation for same service api. 
May be I am missing fundamental idea behind the OSGi services. 
Can you throw more light on this?
BTW yes you are right my approach is very strange, but it is due to our custom framework which resolves the service implementation dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Of course you can have multiple implementations of a service API... you can have as many as you like.

Comment: You can have more than one implementation for the same API. What I was trying to express is that you will need e.g. service properties to distinguish the implementations if you want to avoid looking into the impl by reflection or the like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple implementations of the same service API, and a client queries for an implementation of the service API, it could get any of the implementations. And that's good because the client shouldn't care.

Say for example you have a `Greeting` interface with multiple implementations registered as services, possibly by multiple bundles. If a client asks OSGi for a `Greeting` service then OSGi will simply pick one. After all, if you *just* ask for a `Greeting` without specifying anything else then you should accept any implementation. Clients certainly shouldn't care which particular bundle the service comes from: this is the nature of decoupling.

Incidentally, when this happens OSGi normally chooses the implementation that was registered first (actually the one with the lowest `service.id`, which is an ever-incrementing number, so it's effectively the same thing). This is probably why you see OSGi consistently choosing one particular service.

If your client needs to distinguish between service implementations then you can add properties to the published services and filter on those services. For example one bundle could publish a Greeting service with property `language=en_US` (i.e. US English) and another could publish a Greeting service with `language=de`. If your client only wants greetings in English then it can use a filter like `(language=en*)`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing but I was missing the Private-Package declaration which was causing my service to behave in weird way. So when I would register my new service it was registering same old service with new version.

Comment: Nit: highest service.ranking, THEN lowest service.id.

Comment: @ebullient Yes I just didn't want to complicate my answer too much. That's why I said *normally* chooses the lowest service.id.